# Pyspark dataframe filter based on in between values

Tags: pyspark

I have a **Pyspark** dataframe with below values -

```
[Row(id='ABCD123',  score='28.095238095238095'), Row(id='EDFG456', score='36.2962962962963'), Row(id='HIJK789', score='37.56218905472637'), Row(id='LMNO1011', score='36.82352941176471')]
```

I want only the values from the **DF** which have score **between** the input score value and input score value + 1, say, the input score value is 36 then I want the output **DF** with only two ids - **EDFG456** **& LMNO1011** as their score falls between 36 & 37. I achieved this by doing as follows -

```
input_score_value = 36
input_df = my_df.withColumn("score_num", substring(my_df.score, 1,2))
output_matched = input_df.filter(input_df.score_num == input_score_value)
print(output_matched.take(5))
```

The above code gives the below output, but it takes too long to process 2 mil rows. I was thinking if there is some better way to do this to reduce the response time.

```
[Row(id='EDFG456', score='36.2962962962963'), Row(id='LMNO1011',score='36.82352941176471')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [floor](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.floor).

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import floor
output_matched = input_df.filter(foor(input_df.score_num) == input_score_value)
print(output_matched.take(5))
```

It should be much faster compared to `substring`. Let me know.

Comment: Hi @lrnzcig, Still the same response time, I'm afraid!

Comment: Ok.... well, in the end, you have to read the column for the 2 million rows, that's unavoidable I guess... As far as I know you cannot make it faster, however if you are going to do it many times maybe you could add a new column `floor(input_df.score_num)` and repartition your dataset by that column. The repartition itself will take quite a long time, but afterwards the queries should be quite fast.

Comment: By the way, there was a typo in my answer, I guess you saw it but I corrected it.